# How to pass function name as String in Python 3

Tags: python

I am testing a bunch of functions and want to get the name of the function I tested to be printed to the console.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
passedMsg = "%s passed"
failedMsg = "%s failed"

list_of_functions = [testaddDict(), testaddDictN(), testcharCount(), testcharCount2(), testlookupVal(),
                     testlookupVal2(), testfunRun(), testnumPaths(), testnumbersToSum(), teststreamSquares(),
                     teststreamSquares()]

for i in range(0, len(list_of_functions)):
    if list_of_functions[i]:
        print (passedMsg % str(list_of_functions[i]))
    else:
        print (failedMsg % str(list_of_functions[i]))
```

When I do the above, instead of a function name, I was given:

> True passed

for every iteration. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: `()` invokes the function. Try `[... testaddDict...]`

Comment: First, remove the `()` and then print out `list_of_functions[i].__name__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, have your list hold the function objects (this means that you shouldn't call them, because if you do, you end up holding the *return values* instead).

```
list_of_functions = [testaddDict, testaddDictN, ...]
```

This works because functions are first class objects in python (meaning you can assign them to other variables, and so on). Next, modify your loop as such, to iterate directly over `list_of_functions`:

```
for f in list_of_functions:
    if f():
        print(passedMsg % f.__name__)
    else:
        print(failedMsg % f.__name__)
```

The most important change is that you call the function in the `if` statement, and determine, by its return value, whether it has passed or failed. Print `f.__name__` accordingly, where the `__name__` attribute holds the "name" of the function.

Why I recommend iterating over the function list directly (and not over the `range`), is mainly for efficiency and simplicity sake.

---

Here's a demo with two functions:

```
def f1():
    return True

def f2():
    return False

for f in [f1, f2]:
    if f():
        print(passedMsg % f.__name__)
    else:
        print(failedMsg % f.__name__)
```

```
f1 passed
f2 failed
```

Comment: You may want to call out (er, no pun intended) that you're *calling* the functions in the `if f()` line, since that change is pretty subtle and there are other changes, like skipping the `range` that might distract from the important one.

Comment: @Blckknght Good point. I did point it out but not with enough emphasis. Hopefully it should be clear now.